# c# struct cycled reference via generic

Tags: c#, generics, struct, dynamic-import

When defining a struct it is clear that value of the struct field cannot be the stuct itself. Also, when defining 2 structs and each has a field type of the other, the problem is effectively the same.

But when instead of directly setting type one uses a generic over that type, why is this still a problem?

```
public struct Generic<T> { }
public struct Test1
{
  Generic<Test2> f;
}


public struct Test2
{
  Generic<Test1> f;
}
```

This code compiles fine and generates a dll. When I try to load the dll I get the 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types..' and lists only those types that have relationship described above. If I remove only one of the fields, then load is successfull.  What is going on and how to fix this?

I also noticed that dotnet test explorer does not find any test as long as I have this cycled generic types, but I presume that it is the same problem.

EDIT:

The above code can be compiled into a .dll file. Then, from another project I am using System.Runtime.Loader to dynamically load the dll:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
  var context = new AssemblyLoadContext("context");
  Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath("path-to-dll");
  Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
}
```

On the last line of the example I get the ReflectionTypeLoadException.

Comment: "What is going on?" How many bytes does it take to store a Test2?

Comment: Well, actually none since Generic<T> is empty. But even if it has some primitives the size would be known

Comment: Wait, what? https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUPgMwAEAzgmgMYI0DiApjB8lEwDwAVAHw0A3jQC+FavUaoWNQRwZlyYijXZcefISoSFRAMwDcFaZVoNmrZQ0IUN5LZ268B9hMRPnylmVoiGgBhcU0tGiJCZ0i4pQNiGgA3Yj94yK9CFMJ0yMtJIA= This feels like a bug then. Maybe raise an issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime ?

Comment: The simpler case `Test1 { Generic<Test1> f; }` also fails.

Comment: I have opened the github issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62221)

Comment: I found a duplicate; https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6924

Comment: I found an issue with the same shaped structures as this question, which was already marked as a duplicate. The cause is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this should work. But it doesn't. It's a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6924) with how the runtime loads types.

Fixing this issue would apparently require rewriting the core implementation of how types are loaded. Leading to significant changes in behaviour that could impact a large fraction of existing programs. So far the cost for fixing this issue is considered to be too high to justify doing it.

Comment: If anybody is interested in a usecase:

Comment: My answer was wrong, this is definitely correct.

Comment: The goal was to store an IntPtr to the unmanaged struct and from generic type parameter also have its type. There also is a TypedReference with __makeref() and __refvalue() undocummented functions but there is no way for it to return a reference to the given struct. Using IntPtrs and Marshal/Unsafe classes this is possible. Note that this is generally unsafe and should be used only in time critical parts of the code.